# does order of updates and renders matter?

Tags: rendering, input, game-loop

I know in a game loop there needs to be an order like physics should update before rendering. So, I have created two separate functions: update and render and the game loops like below:

```
while(running) {
    clock.reset();
    for(auto system : systems) {
        system->checkForInput();
        system->update(clock.getElapsedTime());
    }

    for(auto system : systems)
        system->render();
}
```

Some systems have empty render function or empty update functions.

My question is, does the order of updates or renders matter? would it matter if gui is rendered before graphics, or input is updated after physics?

Comment: Yes. Not so much the order of updates, but the order of renders, or "draws" matters. The objects later in the draw order will be drawn over the other objects, so things like GUIs should be drawn last, and the background first.

Comment: To expand on what Pip said, it also matters how you designed your rendering stuff. If you have a set space where you know UI will be, and you purposely account for this space in the rest of your rendering code (i.e you do not render in the "UI space") then order may not matter... It is all in how you chose to design the game.
But in general, yes, it matters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's easiest to think of your order in a single frame, think of it as a series of dependencies.

- User input depends on nothing, so it goes first.
- Objects being updated depend on the user input, so they go second.
- Physics depend on the new updated objects, so it goes third.
- Rendering depends on the latest physics state and object updates, so it goes fourth.
- UI depends on the scene to already be rendered, so it goes fifth.

Comment: Then what about the window? I want the window itself to be a system where it passes the input events to other systems and displays the window. Then should I create a controller and a view where WindowController deals with systems, while the WindowView displays the view? Or it it safe to display the window before any update or render?

Comment: You usually won't need to directly "display" the window each frame. That is usually done in your setup and handled by your graphics framework of choice (DirectX or OpenGL). Your input events, again, would be typically processed at the beginning of the frame

Comment: The thing is my graphics system has no idea if the window system exists. The window system creates the window and the context and displays itself through render. So, I want to know if displaying window before anything else matters

Comment: Here's a better question to be asking: What relies on your Window system? If your graphics system needs your window before anything can be displayed, then I would say it's pretty important to make sure that happens.